# Is it possible to use python in Unity3D for console development?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D Graphing Calculator software in Unity3D. I am struggling to find good numerical/symbolic math libraries written in C/C#. Also, I want to make the calculator programmable (like the TI-84 Calculators everyone uses in school).

I found Python to be a very good language for the backbone of this project. SymPy and NumPy are really good math libraries. And Python would be really good for users to program the calculator. (Here is already a calculator, the Numworks, that supports Python programs. The team ported Python to the hardware.)

If I am developing for the PC, I could just use Python with openGL, or use IronPython in Unity. 
However, I'm developing for the Nintendo 3DS. It may sound like a strange hardware choice, but it makes good sense. The 3DS has a stereoscopic display perfect for showing 3D functions. It has a joy stick to operate the camera. It has a touch screen to handle input. Imagine showing a height map of a 3D function on the lower display. You can use it to trace the function. You can draw a region D on it, and have the 3DS integrate over the region. You can take directional derivatives with your stylus. The possibility is endless. 
The problem, of course, is that Unity doesn't support Python, and IronPython only supports Windows/Mac/Linux/Android.

Do you have any suggestions for me?
For example, any possible way to use python in unity for the 3DS? Any good math library in C/C#? Can I implement a good enough Python interpreter in C# to handle user's program (doesn't have to be complaint)?

Comment: No experience with your scenario, but would [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) (C++) or [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) (C#) help?

Comment: Someone is also developing a [Plug-in for IronPython](https://github.com/exodrifter/unity-python)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Math.Net library for C#, it should have the functionality you need, or you could try IronPython, here is an article that might help you get started.

http://shrigsoc.blogspot.com/2016/07/ironpython-and-unity.html